# Why the last line of my code executes more then one time?

Tags: java

I wrote one program that output like "01234567891010987654321". But the problem is I didn't get why it shows like that. Can you please explain about last line of output.

my code is:

```
class Demo{

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int i = 0;
    show(i);

  }

  public static void  show(int i) {
    if(i<=9)
    {
      System.out.print(i++);
      show(i);
    }
    System.out.print(i--);
  }

}
```

Comment: Because `show` is recursive.

Comment: sir actually i am surprised with this line  "   System.out.print(i--);" . it was execute more then one time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can break the output into two parts:
first part:

```
012345678910
```

this part is printed from within your if statement- it will run recursively from 0 to 10, since for those i is <= than 9.

second part:

```
10987654321
```

this one is coming from `System.out.print(i--);` after your if statement- in the first part you recursed into your show method, now you are recursing out of it, from 10 to 1 (you won't get 0 because of your ++)

if you want the last line to be executed only once, do it in an `else` segment, that way you won't get it on all the times you enter show method

Answer (score 1):

Put graphically, this happens:

```
if (i <= 9) {
    System.out.print(i++);
    if (i <= 9) {
        System.out.print(i++);
        if (i <= 9) {
            System.out.print(i++);
            // etc, until i == 10
            System.out.print(i--);
        }
        System.out.print(i--);
    }
    System.out.print(i--);
}
System.out.print(i--);
```

The last line *always* executes one more time; imagine if i starts at 20 - this nested called would not execute, but the last line would execute once.